# Updated pip successfully, but got an error message after

Tags: python, cmd, pip

Recently updated pip from 20.1 to 20.1.1. It all went well except for some reason I got an error message after it. I ran pip --version to see if it was changed to 20.1.1 and it did. Should I be concerned about the error message though? I'm on Windows 10 if that makes any difference.

```
C:\Users\Isabella>pip install --upgrade pip
Collecting pip
  Downloading pip-20.1.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (1.5 MB)
     |████████████████████████████████| 1.5 MB 726 kB/s
Installing collected packages: pip
  Attempting uninstall: pip
    Found existing installation: pip 20.1
    Uninstalling pip-20.1:
      Successfully uninstalled pip-20.1
ERROR: Could not install packages due to an EnvironmentError: [WinError 5] Access is denied: 'C:\\Users\\Isabella\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-uninstall-8mkzjz1n\\pip.exe'
Consider using the `--user` option or check the permissions.


C:\Users\Isabella>pip --version
pip 20.1.1 from c:\users\isabella\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages\pip (python 3.8)
```

EDIT: Tried doing it with `--user` and it said it was already up-to-date, so I guess there's nothing to worry about? Thanks for the replies.

Answer (score 0):

You can type the command with user permission i.e, `pip install --upgrade pip --user`

Or you also try by running cmd as Administrator and run `pip install --upgrade pip`

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks, says it's already up-to-date so I guess I can ignore the error?

Comment: @Isabella Great, yes, you can ignore the error as it is already up-to-date. Please accept my answer if it was helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to Stack Overflow! 
If you read the outputs closely, it says :

`ERROR: Could not install packages due to an EnvironmentError: [WinError 5] Access is denied: 'C:\\Users\\Isabella\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-uninstall-8mkzjz1n\\pip.exe'
Consider using the "--user" option or check the permissions.`

#### Access is denied

and

#### Consider using the "--user" option or check the permissions.

or you could try upgrading pip inside a virtualenv and let us know how it goes! :) goodluck!

Comment: Thanks for the welcome! See my question is why did the error even show up if it installed successfully. I did it with --user and it said it's up-to-date, so I have no idea why the error popped up. I guess I can ignore it then?

Comment: Well, it's not a good practice if you ignore errors but if you tried it with the --user tag and it said up to date, that means it installed somehow. If any questions comes up, there's always google and people in stackoverflow eager to help :)